# how to display routing data online (with the lines between points)

Tags: mapping

I have a set of routing data, in both CSV or KML format. It is basically a list of Lat / Lon and some supporting information. 
I am looking for a way to display this as a route (e.g. with lines between the points in the order they appear in the list) online. Ideally a free option, as I'm not likely to need it again in the near future.

I have found hundreds (maybe an exageration) of ways of plotting the points, but not one that will include the lines. I'm trying to avoid the long and tedious process of converting one of these to an image and drawing the lines by hand.

Can anyone suggest such a site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was asked on a google group for google maps. The user received an answer that pointed him towards the google map API. Given how other apps / web pages do this using google maps (never seen it done any other way) I would imagine this would be the best route to go down as its probably something they have built into the service.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3/F_iroBiBeww

Comment: thanks for that. I was able to modify my KML file to include the lines and import it into Google Earth / Google Maps.